# Select the first element of a list with prototype

Tags: select, prototypejs

I have a form with 3 lists like this and I need every time one of the lists change put the others in cero 0, I need this in prototype or pure Javascript

```
<select id="1" onchange="resetall()">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="2" onchange="resetall()">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="3" onchange="resetall()">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GWYGu/4/) using Prototype

Basically, it finds all `select` elements with the class `resetOthers`, and listens for the `onchange` event (don't use the `onchange` HTML attribute - it's cleaner to add the JavaScript behavior via JavaScript once the page has loaded).

When a select changes, it loops through the select elements, and sets each to the value of the first option (except for the one that triggered the event, of course).